# CD-ROM for Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats 2Ed

Tags: file, graphics, specifications, formats

I bought the Second Edition of this Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats (ISBN 1-56592-161-5) at Amazon as Brand New, but it came without the companion CD (something highly unexpected).

I have been looking for the companion CD-ROM in case I get no compensation at Amazon, as I have understood that it can be legally distributed under Creative Commons (at least the First Edition) and I have only found the CD-ROM for the First Edition at the Internet Archive:

[Companion CD, First Edition, 1994, at Archive.org](http://archive.org/search.php?query=Encyclopedia%20of%20Graphics%20File%20Formats%20AND%20collection%3Acdbbsarchive)

http://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/

I have also found several sites, apparently with the contents of the Second Edition, but not specifically the CD-ROM, which is what I only care about.

Does anybody know where can I (obviously legally) find the companion CD-ROM for the Second Edition, and how much of a difference there is in the included source code and file format specifications from those of the First Edition?

Answer (score 0):

I found the original contents of the Second Edition at its official FTP address:

**Second Edition (FTP):**

ftp://ftp.ora.com/pub/examples/gff/

---

---

**Second Edition (HTTP):**

http://examples.oreilly.com/gff/

---

---

---

You must basically download all of the files at that URL and save them locally. Then, you must change the URL directory to http://examples.oreilly.com/gff/CDROM/ and **you must merge** all of those contents with what you already downloaded. **Merge without changing directories nor creating a CDROM directory.**

Then, for Windows, you need to use the `GFF.exe` file from `w95102b1.zip` and replace the one in the installation directory, or else the Mosaic viewer won't find any HTML files for the digital version, included in all that we downloaded.